# Sharepoint Profile Replication Engine permissions warnings

Tags: powershell, my-site, user-profile

I'm trying to use Microsoft's [User Profile Service Replication Engine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc663011.aspx) that packs with the Sharepoint 2010 Administration Tools download and I'm running into problems.

Specifically I am endeavouring to use the `Start-SPProfileServiceIncrementalReplication` commandlet with something like this:

```
Start-SPProfileServiceIncrementalReplication -Source http://sourceserver:1234 -Target http://targetserver/my -DoSocialReplication -Credential $credentialvar
```

I have configured `$credentialvar` to use the credentials of a user who has Local Administrator and Farm Administrator rights on both source and target server.

The response I get to this is "Argument Credential does not have enough permissions to access web service."

The problem I am having is that it isn't telling me, and I don't know where to find out, *what* web service is causing the permission error, or indeed what server I should be looking on. Does the Replication Engine log this information anywhere? Will the SharePoint logs tell me? I can include a -EnableInstrumentation parameter but I can't work out what that actually does.

I feel like I'm having to perform fine needlepoint blindfold, in the dark, with boxing gloves on. It is a touch frustrating. Can anyone recommend how I can find what is causing the problem so I can progress forward to the next inexplicable error message.

Edited to add: Tracing the HTTP request reveals that my first POST request to `http://targetserver/_vti_bin/userprofilechangeservice.asmx` is returning the following message: `soap:Server Server was unable to process request. ---> Access Denied: Only administrators can call GetChanges`

I am using credentials as a local machine administrator and a farm administrator for both SharePoint sites, so I'm not sure how much more administrator I can be.

Comment: I have the same issue.. do you find any solution for the above issue..
please post the solution here..

Comment: @james, I'm afraid I never found a solution to this problem. I had to move on to some different work so I think I gave up around this point.

Answer (score 1):

I had spent a few hours trying to get the initial full sync working but it kept failing with an access denied trying to call http://my.sites/_vti_bin/userprofilechangeservice.asmx?op=GetChanges (I gave the account running the command every permission I could think of, full control on the service app, farm admin, local admin etc etc). Simply switching to central admin of the source and destination environment sorted the problem. Who knows how long I would have spent working that out if it wasn't for this post.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i am having the same issue,  everything was working perfectly and suddenly after installing Aug 2015 CU on my server,  one of the servers are having issues in starting replication engine.  I didnt quite get this solution of switching to central admin.  could you elaborate more